# Error while pushing from bitbucket repo to heroku. It says my repo is a shallow clone

Tags: node.js, heroku, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I created a pipeline to deploy my code from Bitbucket repo to Heroku server.

my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm install
          - git push https://heroku:<my heroku api key>@git.heroku.com/<my heroku app's name>.git HEAD
```

After pushing my code to my bitbucket repo, the pipeline runs, but fails while pushing the code to heroku git.
Below is the error:

```
Push rejected, source repository is a shallow clone. Unshallow it with `git fetch --all --unshallow` and try pushing again.
```

But then by bit bucket repo is not shallow. The command `git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository` returns `false`.

Comment: She shallow repository might refer to the heroku git repo (`git push <source> <branch>`). Heroku does a bunch of weird stuff with their git repository.  
When you do an automatic deploy on Heroku for instance the git master branch is for instance "empty" even though your app was pushed successfuly and is running fine on Heroku. When you want to git push to the master branch you need to fix that heroku git first.

Comment: Thought so... So what would be a straight forward approach to resolve this? :)

Comment: Locally: git clone your gitbucket. Add heroku remote to your local git repo. Force push to the heroku git. Then your pipeline should work. OR: git clone your heroku git, add your bitbucket to your local git repo. Git pull from bitbucket and forcepush into your heroku remote. (Second is better if you are authenticating through the heroku cli.)

Comment: Hey thanks it worked. I usually create the pipeline and let it push to the heroku's git from my repo. I never had to push directly to heroku's git. I wonder what went happened this time. Anyways the issue is resolved...Thanks mate! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following git command before the `push`

```
git filter-branch -- --all
```

So it would be in your script:

```
...
- git filter-branch -- --all
- git push https://heroku:<my heroku api key>@git.heroku.com/<my heroku app's name>.git HEAD
```